# Access denied when changing Oracle 11g database port from SQL Command Line

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlcommand

I'm trying to change the port of my Oracle DB from SQL Command Line but I'm getting Access Denied.

[image]

Why am I getting this restriction and how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I connected with `system@xe` as a username and executed the command successfully: `exec DMBS_xdb.sethttpport('7070');`

The problem appears to be that if you don't log in with your SYSTEM account, or fail to extend privileges to your other user, you will be denied the ability to change your installation port.